# Entity Framework 7 - How to create dbSet from iEntityType

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a C# console app using EF 7 (EF Core) and I am dynamically creating entities (using roslyn) then adding them to the dbContext model.   What I need to do is then create a DbSet for the entity.

In my context I am wanting to do something like...

```
iEntityType? newEntity = this.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(....).SingleOrDefault();
Set<...>()
```

The issue I have is what to put into the Set command. It takes a *TEntity : where class*, which the dynamic entity is (it was compiled public class x and newEntity.ClrType.IsClass == true).

Does anyone know how to get the TEntity from the iEntityType ?

Comment: Capitalization matters.

Comment: If you don't know the `Type` at runtime (or via generics) you'll need to use `.MakeGenericMethod()` to get the correct `DbContext.Set<T>()` then invoke it. There's no supported non-generic equivalent. .... or perhaps "via roslyn" create a method for this purpose.

Comment: eg you could define a `static abstract` interface method, then implement it on each entity type in order to define any useful helper methods like `public static IQueryable Set(DbContext db) => db.Set<X>();`

Comment: All the power of EF+LINQ is shown in compile time. But you are doing something in runtime. In this case, EF is not your assistant, just give it up.

Comment: Thanks folks, I'll ask the question on the EF forum as well.  I was asking here in case someone had already solved the issue in a different way.  I'll leave the question open in case it gets resolved at a later date :)

Comment: If your types are being created "dynamically at runtime" are you also running migrations dynamically at runtime?

Comment: No I am not, I was just trying to read the tables without having to create compile time types.

Comment: I will close with question as after a bit more research with EF, I can see that it will not be possible to do what I intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research with the EF code I discovered that one cannot create dynamic DbSet as TEntity has to be defined at compile time by design.